# Cannot get id of selectItems of selectOneMenu in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

The Id (personBean.idSelectedItem) always return null. though i can select and change my values of drop down list but Id is still null, not changing accordingly.
Please help me, below is my code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{personBean.idSelectedItem}" immediate="true"  onchange="EnableDisable()">
  <f:selectItems value="#{personBean.apptDuration}" />               
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

My bean is:

```
private String idSelectedItem = null;
private List<SelectItem> apptDuration = null;
public String getIdSelectedItem() {
   System.out.println("getIdSelectedItem == " + idSelectedItem);
   return idSelectedItem;}

public void setIdSelectedItem(String idSelectedItem) {
    this.idSelectedItem = idSelectedItem;
    System.out.println("setIdSelectedItem == " + idSelectedItem);
}

public List<SelectItem> getApptDuration() {
  if (apptDuration == null) {
      apptDuration = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
      apptDuration.add(new SelectItem("P1", "Day(s)"));
      apptDuration.add(new SelectItem("P2", "5 min"));
      apptDuration.add(new SelectItem("P3", "10 min"));
      apptDuration.add(new SelectItem("P4", "15 min"));
  }
  return apptDuration;
}

public void setApptDuration(List<SelectItem> apptDuration) {
    this.apptDuration = apptDuration;
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Does the `System.out.println("set...` get called during the form model update?

Comment: Is the form submitted at all (do you have a `h:commandButton` o similar that you click?)

Comment: This is inside form tag. but i am new to jsf i want to submit form without page reload. how i will do it please post sample example thanks

Comment: What is the scope of the backing bean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using a4j:support: Now it works fine not reloading my page every time :

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id="appt" value="#{personBean.idSelectedItem}" >
                 <f:selectItems value="#{personBean.apptDuration}"/>
                 <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{personBean.changeID}" oncomplete="DisableFields()" reRender="updatedId"/>  
                 <h:inputHidden id="updatedId" value="#{personBean.updatedApptId}"/>                 
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to reload you must use Ajax, (`a4j` if you stick to RichFaces).

Use `a4j:commandButton` (or similar) for explicitly sending the ajax request, or `a4j:actionListener` inside the `h:selectOneMenu` to send the request/model update when you change the selected value. Something like (I am writting from memory>

```
 <h:selectOneMenu id=...>
   <h:selectItems .../>
   <a4j:actionListener listener="#{myBean.myControllerMethod}"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Also `f:ajax` serves the same purpose without RichFaces.

Comment: the tag  (a4j:actionListener) is not supported em using 3.3.2 version of richfaces and a4j

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.2.SR1/en/tlddoc/a4j/ajaxListener.html then

Comment: Please any other solution it doesn't help me :(